# Replace some dots(.) with commas(,) with RegEx and awk or sed

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I want to replace dots with commas for some but not all matches:

```
hostname_metric (Index: 1) to hostname;metric (avg);22.04.2015 13:40:00;3.0000;22.04.2015 02:05:00;2.0000;22.04.2015 02:00:00;650.7000;2.2594;
```

The outcome should look like this:

```
hostname_metric (Index: 1) to hostname;metric (avg);22.04.2015 13:40:00;3,0000;22.04.2015 02:05:00;2,0000;22.04.2015 02:00:00;650,7000;2,2594;
```

I was able to identify the RegEx which should work to find the correct dots.

```
;[0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{4}
```

But how can I replace them with a comma with awk or sed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using `[0-9]{1,}` when you can just use `[0-9]`

Answer (score 4):

Adding some capture groups to the regex in your question, you can use this sed one-liner:

```
sed -r 's/(;[0-9]{1,})\.([0-9]{4})/\1,\2/g' file
```

This matches and captures the part before and after the `.` and uses them in the replacement string.

On some versions of sed, you may need to use `-E` instead of `-r` to enable Extended Regular Expressions. If your version of sed doesn't understand either switch, you can use basic regular expressions and add a few escape characters:

```
sed 's/\(;[0-9]\{1,\}\)\.\([0-9]\{4\}\)/\1,\2/g' file
```

Comment: It works on RHEL but I need this to work on Solaris. I thought it won't make any difference but I does: sed: command garbled: s/\(;[0-9]\{1,\})\.\([0-9]\{4\}\)/\1,\2/g

Comment: The second example should work - it looks like you're missing the escape characters around the parentheses.

Comment: I did this: bash# sed 's/\(;[0-9]\{1,\})\.\([0-9]\{4\}\)/\1,\2/g' file > file_correct

Comment: Ok, found it: sed 's/\(;[0-9]\{1,\}\)\.\([0-9]\{4\}\)/\1,\2/g' file

Comment: @sunn_bmixer there was actually a typo in my answer...sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

`sed 's/\(;[0-9]\+\)\.\([0-9]\{4\}\)/\1,\2/g'` should do the trick.

Comment: The OP talked about replacing some dots(.) with commas(,) with RegEx and the string shown before and after has 143 characters, the difference between the two is 4 of the dots(.) were replaced with commas(,) but both strings are still 143 characters long. Using your suggested sed command the output string is only 139 characters long having removed the leading semi-colon(;) prior to the dots(.) being replaced with commas(,). So obvious ultimately this solution fails even though it replaced the targeted characters and IMO should have not been up-voted. http://imgur.com/GkeO34G